# Query of the execution step of shell command `ls > list`

Tags: linux, shell

```bash
root@VM-0-11-debian:~/linux/2023/01# ls
root@VM-0-11-debian:~/linux/2023/01# ls > list
root@VM-0-11-debian:~/linux/2023/01# ls
list
root@VM-0-11-debian:~/linux/2023/01# cat list 
list
```

I know that `>` will redirect stdout to file. it will create the file if not present, otherwise replace it.

I would like to ask that is the shell command `ls > list` implementation process as I described below?

1)As the file named `list` not exists, so create a file named `list` first.

2)`ls` command will list the directory content(list). the content listed(list) will be in the standard output.

3)Add the content of the standard output(list) to the file named `list` in a replaced way.

My personal understanding of the implementation process as described above, I hope you can give me some guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file redirection operator `>` is handled by your shell and any file to which you write will be created/truncated *before* the binary is started. That's why you can see the file name `list` in the content of the file: the file has already been created before the `ls` process was started.

So yes, your understanding is correct.

This is why it is not possible to do something like `sort txt > txt` – the file `txt` will be truncated *before* `sort` reads it. You will end up with an empty file.